# Python program that writing in an excel file is writing last line only

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, openpyxl

I have installed openpyxl module and now I am trying to write some data into an excel file, to fill up the excel file in one sheet in this way :

`["01/01/2016", "05:00:00", 3]` into row 1, colums A, B, C

`["01/02/2016", "06:00:00", 4]` into row 2, colums A, B, C

`["01/03/2016", "07:00:00", 5]` into row 3, colums A, B, C

`["01/04/2016", "08:00:00", 6]` into row 4, colums A, B, C

`["01/05/2016", "09:00:00", 7]` into row 5, colums A, B, C

When I try running the code, I obtain the following results :

- row 1, columns A - 01/05/2016
- row 1, columns B - 09:00:00
- row 1, columns C - 7

**Code:**

```
import os, sys
from openpyxl import Workbook
from datetime import datetime

dt = datetime.now()

list_values = [["01/01/2016", "05:00:00", 3],
              ["01/02/2016", "06:00:00", 4],
              ["01/03/2016", "07:00:00", 5],
              ["01/04/2016", "08:00:00", 6],
              ["01/05/2016", "09:00:00", 7]]

wb = Workbook()
sheet = wb.active
sheet.title = "Data"

row = 1
sheet['A' + str(row)] = "Date"
sheet['B' + str(row)] = "Hour"
sheet['C' + str(row)] = "Value"

for item in list_values:
    sheet['A' + str(row)] = item[0]
    sheet['B' + str(row)] = item[1]
    sheet['C' + str(row)] = item[2]
    row =+ 1

filename = 'Book_3.xlsx'
os.chdir(sys.path[0])
os.system('start excel.exe "%s\\%s"' %(sys.path[0], filename,))
```

**Result:**
[image: result]

Comment: You should always use `ws.cell()` or `ws.iter_rows()` for this kind of thing. It means you don't have to manage your own counters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were using =+ instead of +=. Below code should work. I also change sys.path[0] to os.getcwd() which writes to the current working directory. Also added wb.save, as else code didn't produce an output.

```
import os, sys
from openpyxl import Workbook
from datetime import datetime

dt = datetime.now()

list_values = [["01/01/2016", "05:00:00", 3],
              ["01/02/2016", "06:00:00", 4],
              ["01/03/2016", "07:00:00", 5],
              ["01/04/2016", "08:00:00", 6],
              ["01/05/2016", "09:00:00", 7]]

wb = Workbook()
sheet = wb.active
sheet.title = "Data"

row = 1
sheet['A' + str(row)] = "Date"
sheet['B' + str(row)] = "Hour"
sheet['C' + str(row)] = "Value"

for item in list_values:
    sheet['A' + str(row)] = item[0]
    sheet['B' + str(row)] = item[1]
    sheet['C' + str(row)] = item[2]
    row += 1


dest_filename = 'Book_3.xlsx'
wb.save(filename = dest_filename)
os.chdir(os.getcwd())
os.system('start excel.exe "%s\\%s"' %(os.getcwd(), filename,))
```

Comment: Great to hear. If it works, please consider marking this as the accepted answer and upvoting.